# How to change binwidth of a histogram with the layer function

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, layer

I try to make a histogram with the layer function of ggplot2 from 100 random numbers created by rlnorm(100).

So far this is my code;

```
library(ggplot2)
verdeling <- rlnorm(100)
verdeling <- as.data.frame(verdeling)
verdeling$num <- verdeling$verdeling
joost$verdeling <- verdeling$num
    p <- ggplot(data = verdeling, mapping = aes(x = num))


    p2 <- p + layer(
      geom = "bar",
      stat = "bin",
      position = "stack",



    )
    p2
```

How do I change the binwidth of the histogram?
Normally i make histograms without the layer function and it was as easy as binwidth = x.

Thanks in advance.

Ruben

Answer (score 0):

When using the `layer` function, pass additional parameters to `params` as a list.

```
p2 <- p + layer(
    geom = "bar",
    stat = "bin",
    position = "stack",
    # Add binwidth = x as a list to params
    params = list(binwidth = x)
)
```